# How can i compare achievements with Game Center in iOS7

Tags: ios, game-center

I remember i could easily compare my achievements in previous version of iOS/GC, but now i can't.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Game Center > Games > *select a game* > Achievements

or what did you mean by "compare my achievements"?